# How to place Fb:request-form inside a popup?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to place [Facebook's request form](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:request-form) inside a popup? Google is failing me atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Okay I found the answer.](http://translate.google.com.ph/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=tl&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fhudson.su%2F2009%2F12%2F24%2Finvite-dialog-by-standard-facebook-tools%2F&sl=ru&tl=en&swap=1)